# normalizeTypeName is undefined

Tags: javascript, breeze

I am trying to get metadata back from my "contact" object to breeze so I can map the metadata to a "contactdto" object. On the server I have a Web API function called GetContactsMetadata

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Contact> GetContactsMetadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Contacts.Take(1);
    }
```

I'm sure I'll remove the IQueryable and/or list once I get this example running. on the client I have the following

```
        //GetContactsMetadata
        var myJsonResultsAdapter = new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({
            name: "GetContactsMetadata",
            extractResults: function (json) {
                return json.results;
            },
            visitNode: function (node, parseContext, nodeContext) {
                var entityType = normalizeTypeName(node.$type);
                var propertyName = nodeContext.propertyName;
                var ignore = propertyName && propertyName.substr(0, 1) === "$";

                return {
                    entityType: entityType,
                    nodeId: node.$id,
                    nodeRefId: node.$ref,
                    ignore: ignore
                };
            }
        });
        var dataService = new breeze.DataService({
            serviceName: 'api/contacts',
            jsonResultsAdapter: myJsonResultsAdapter
        });
        var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: dataService });
```

It keeps erroring in chrome with: "normalizeTypeName is not defined". Am I calling the JsonResultsAdapter correctly?

Comment: This error is an indication that the `normalizeTypeName()` function is not in active scope. The browser can't find the function when it tries to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have been clearer in the example.

The *normalizeTypeName* method is a method you as the dev would write that would take some property on the node and return a Breeze EntityType or a Breeze EntityType name.  If you actually know the type name and are only using this adapter for a single type of query you can do something as simple as this:.

```
 visitNode: function (node, parseContext, nodeContext) {
     return {
         entityType: "Contact" // or "ContactDTO" depending on what you are calling the type on the client.
     };
 }
```